# Problem with my developer certificate

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

Yesterday I reinstalled my OS after the upgrade to lion and now when I try to build my app to my device I get an error.

I don't have a backup of my previous certificate so what I must do to fix this?

I already have 5 Apps on the App Store. If I create a new certificate will I have to update all of them?

As I understand it, I must revoke my previous certificate and then create a new one, but if I do that will I lose all my Apps already on the App Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login to the [iOS Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/index.action) and re-download your certificate(s).